# What's the term for a value x that satisfies the constraint $f(x) = f$ for a function f?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, computer-science

I know that $x$ is called the fixed point of a function $f$ if it satisfies the constraint $f(x) = x$.

However, for a function $f$ if there exists some value $x$ such that $f(x) = f$ then what is the term for the value $x$ with respect to $f$.

---

Consider the following function in JavaScript:

```
var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
```

Now `bindable` is the function $f$ that I'm talking about. It satisfies the constraint $f(x) = f$ for the value `bind`:

```
bindable(bind) = bindable;
```

I know that I shouldn't express mathematics in terms of programming but I didn't know any other way to put it.

---

Consider that `bind` has the following type definition:

```
(a b -> c) a -> (b -> c)
```

It takes a function of type `a b -> c` and zero or more arguments which grouped together have the type `a` and returns another function of type `b -> c` where `b` has the type of the rest of the arguments grouped together.

Hence `bind(bind)` has the following type definition:

```
(a b -> c) -> (a -> (b -> c))
```

Let `bindable = bind(bind)`, then`bindable(bind)` also has the same type definition:

```
(a b -> c) -> (a -> (b -> c))
```

i.e. `bindable(bind) = bindable`.

Comment: Why do you write mathematical expressions like this? Enclose them in dollar signs for them to show properly. Also, what do you mean by $f(x)=f$? It is not possible in standard set theory (it's a violation of regularity), and I can't think of a case when this would be useful.

Comment: What is $f$? Is it a number? A function?

Comment: @tomasz - Programming habit from StackOverflow. Sorry.

Comment: @Daryl - $f$ is a function. I'll update my question.

Comment: If $\,f\,$ is a function, then $\,f:A\to B\,$ , with $\,A\,,\,B\,$ some sets. If $\,f\notin B\,$ , then the  equation $\;f(x)=f\;$ makes absolutely no sense at all.

Comment: Given that he is talking computer science, why is everybody telling him that $f(x)=f$ is not possible? This is quite common in lambda calculus, for example.

Comment: @DonAntonio then $f\in B$ here?

Comment: Unfortunately, your example with bind is not particularly useful, since it requires knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - True that. I'll try to explain it in terms of Haskell type definitions or Forth stack reductions.

Comment: @CBenni , I don't know...but *I think* not and the OP may be confussing stuff here, yet the OP hasn't yet addressed this *directly*, and he just added some programming-like stuff I've no idea about.

Comment: @DonAntonio - I pretty clear about what I'm trying to convey. I update my answer. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: @CBenni - Yes indeed. Here $f\in A$ and $x\in A$ and $\,f:A\to A\,$.

Comment: @Aadit: You may have better luck dropping the idea that you're talking about the evaluation of a generalized notion of function, and instead asking something even more general. e.g. "if you have a binary operation with the property that $fx=f$ for some values $f$ and $x$, how might you describe the situation?" If you *really* need terminology specialized to your particular context of interest, then you're probably better off asking someplace more specialized. (Or, at least, explicitly stating the field of interest you are asking about)

Comment: Looking at it from a type theory perspective, $f$ would have to have a type that satisfies $T = A \to T$, where $A$ is the type of the argument. You can express this using inductive types; structually, it looks like a bit like a reverse stream. I'm not sure it has a name, though, and I'm also not sure what it would be good for.

Comment: In basic lambda calculus, we don't really talk about a domain set - we don't care about sets. There are models of lambda calculus that are composed of a set $A$ and a map $A\to A^A$ with various properties, but the lambda calculus notion of a function is not philisophically the same as the set theory idea of a function.

Comment: It's clear that the fundamental problem here is that the notion of a function in computer science and the notion of function in mathematics are not the same. As the other answerer notes below, lambda calculus terms are usually not called "functions" by mathematicians, while they are frequently used as models for what programmers call "functions."  It would seem to me that the OP is asking about is the programming idea, not the set theory idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there is a name for this. If there is, it would be something from lambda calculus.

Unlike fixed points, where $f(x)=x$, I'm not sure what the value would be in such a concept.

There is a sense in which $f(x)=f$ is also a fixed point. Namely, if $D=\lambda y.\lambda g. g(y)$, then $f$ is a fixed point of $Dx$. But I'm not sure if that really gives you anything.

You might consider asking this question at [the StackExchange site dedicate to computer science questions](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

This situation never occurs in ordinary mathematics, because in order to specify a function you need to specify the codomain $C$ (set of possible values the function could take) first, and that set cannot contain any functions that have $C$ as codomain. Or in terms of set theory (though that point of view does not seem the most important to me) the  set of functions $X\to Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$; if some $x \in X$ and $f\in Y$ satisfied $f(x)=f$ then one would have $(x,f)\in f$ and since also $f \in^+ (x,f)$ where $\in^+$ is the "transitive closure" of the relation $\in$ (just how depends on the definition of ordered pairs) one would have $f\in^+ f$ violating the [axiom of regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity).

This being said one can imagine "function application" is just some externally defined operator that takes $f$ and $x$ to produce a value written $f(x)$, and in this case $f(x)=f$ is possible. To give it a name I would say $f$ is a fixed point for $x$ under reverse function application (being-applied-to).

Comment: What do you call "ordinary mathematics?" Lambda calculus is something I learned as an undergraduate. It doesn't occur in the standard definition of function in set theory, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Lambda calculus is certainly mathematics, but lambda expression are not functions in the ordinary mathematical sense of the term. Indeed this is exactly an example of an external operation defined on the set of pairs of (equivalence classes of?) lambda terms that is somewhat arbitrarily called "function application" (one could have called it multiplication or something else).

Comment: And yet, given the poster is talking about computer functions, which are "not functions" in this set theory sense, then that would seem to be his intent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Which is why I wrote the second paragraph. But this being a math forum, I felt I needed to address it for mathematicians as well.